# Adding Logo to a Font

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm working on redesigning my small business website, so i figured, why not learn something while doing it! :p

Anyways... I am trying to get my logo into the HTML.

The --free and open-source... I might add-- template I used had a placeholder glyph that looks dang good. I cannot find out how to add my logo by making it a glyph. I have a SVG/AI/png/etc of my logo, but cannot figure out how to easily edit the font file to add glyphs.
I currently have it set as an image, but since this template updates sizes of things if u r on desktop, vs mobile, it doesn't look right.
I got it to kinda work with the BirdFont app to edit the font, but then when I edited it, all of the other glyphs went away, and the sizes were off.
With the pre-installed glyphs, you summon a glyph by:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-GLYPH_NAME_HERE"></span>
```

Also, in BirdFont, i couldn't edit the name that goes to glyphicon-GLYPH_NAME_HERE, so i just edited one of them that I know i won't be using.

TL:DR; What's an easy, quick, reliable way to edit a font file, containing glyphs, to add my logo -- as a glyph?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Fontastic](http://app.fontastic.me/), which allows you to create fonts with lots of vector icons from multiple sources, and add your own icons (Add more Icons -> Import icons) from SVG files or SVG fonts.

Comment: Yup that works! This was MUCH easier than how I thought!

Answer (score 0):

edit the glyphicon css file for a glyph that you aren't using, and set that value to your new image.